# what phrase to use to convey the idea of "my first attempt"

Tags: phrases, expressions

I had tried photography as serious hobby for the first time and I have made an album. I want to expresses the idea to the world that this is my first attempt. Few things come to my mind like "my first try at photography" or "my first hand at photography". I do not know if these statements are correct, so can someone suggest something or at-least verify these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is reasonable to refer to “my first try at photography”, but your other phrase, “my first hand at photography”, does not make sense.  (The usual senses of *[firsthand, first hand, first-hand](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/firsthand#English)* are related to personal experience moreso than to a first attempt.)

You might refer to the album as a first or initial *[effort](http://www.onelook.com/?w=effort&ls=a)*, *[attempt](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attempt#Noun)*, or *[endeavor](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/endeavor#Noun)*.  It can also be called a *[trial run](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trial_run)* or a *[maiden voyage](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/maiden_voyage)*. You can also say you are a *[beginner](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beginner#Noun)*,  *[novice](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/novice#Noun)*,   *[tyro](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tyro#Noun)*, or *[amateur](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amateur#Noun)*.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with "this is my first try at photography," or "this is my first serious attempt at photography."

One less formal way to say it is, "this is my first *stab* at photography." NOAD defines *stab* as "an attempt to do (something)."

Yet another way to say it is to use the word *debut*. From NOAD:

> **debut**: a person's first appearance or performance in a particular capacity or role

So, you could say something like, "Take it easy on me, this is my debut as a serious photographer."